# Windows 7 - remove custom shortcut in start menu

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I've set a shortcut on the OpenOffice Writer in the Windows Start Menu.
After installing newer OpenOffice version this item was overriden by the new item (just with different icon).

The problem is that the shortcut to the previous item remainded: when I try to set the same shortcut on the new item - Windows (probably) tries to find not existing item and run it. I think it may be the case of the shortcut bond to not existing item, because I lose focus from Properties dialog when I try to set it and nothing happens.

How can I remove this shortcut so that I can reassign it to the correct item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply reboot and you'll be able to assign the now unused keyboard shortcut to the new program shortcut in the Start Menu.